# How can I connect to Azure Repos TFVC repository from Jenkins with the TFS plugin?

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I am trying to connect my Jenkins job to a new Azure Repos TFVC repository. Jenkins fails and returns the following error when I attempt to connect to the root URL for my Azure Devops organization (macfarmw):

```
Building on master in workspace J:\Builds\Jenkins\TestAzureDevopsRepos
Deleting workspace as the configuration has changed since a build was performed on this computer.
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSUnauthorizedException: Access denied connecting to TFS server https://macfarmw.visualstudio.com/ (authenticating as matthew_macfarland@dril-quip.com)
...
```

If I try it with a URL to the Azure Repo for the specific project I get this:

```
Building on master in workspace J:\Builds\Jenkins\TestAzureDevopsRepos
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The SOAP endpoint https://macfarmw.visualstudio.com/Project01/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404
com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.exceptions.EndpointNotFoundException: The SOAP endpoint https://macfarmw.visualstudio.com/Project01/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404
...
```

I have checked the following items

- Server URL: works in browser to access the repo
- Login Name/User Password: works in browser to access the repo

Jenkins version: 2.176

TFS Plugin version: 5.142.0

The TFS plugin is working fine for my on-premises TFS server.

What changes are needed to make this connect?